# Filter the data frame based on the column names without using index in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with 30 columns and I want to filter the data frame by column name.

I have tried it by the .iloc method and it works. but instead of going with the index, I want to do it with the string (column names). Maybe, later on, I will add some columns at the starting of the data frame.

df = df.iloc[:,5:8]

My Data frame:

```
W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, W6, W7, W8, W9, W10, W11, W12, W13, .......
70, 60, 90, 100, 110, 130, 150, 120, 110,200, 230, 95
100,200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100,1200
200,400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 2400
```

Expected Result:

```
W6, W7, W8
130, 150, 120
600,700,800
1200,1400,1600
```

Comment: Try this with `df = df.loc[:, 'W6':'W8']`

Comment: For reference `iloc` is position with the index, and `loc` is label.

Comment: Oh. It works. I wasn't familiar with the loc method. I am a beginner in python and pandas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
df[["W6", "W7", "W8"]]
```

Comment: Yes. It will work and even with the indexes it's working, but if I have 100 columns or more, this is not a good solution.

Comment: You said you want to do this "with the string (column names)". So, I presume, you do have an array with those strings somewhere. Simply pass it to `df[array_of_strings]`. If you don't have an array of strings, then I don't see how you can tell a computer which strings to pick, unless you hardcode them.